# compare strings two files with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to compare field 5 from file1 with field 2 from file2 and show lines when they are equal.

file1

```
"202005";"RS";"4301602";"CITY";"12651500714";"***.368.660-**";"TESTE TESTE";"-2";""
"202005";"RS";"4301602";"BAGE";"00000000000";"***.977.440-**";"XXXXX XXXEZ";"-2";""
```

file2

```
"93330090006";"12651500714";"TESTE XX";
"01168199018";"16108835006";"SOME NAME";
```

I searched and used a lot of codes, but it's not working.
My last code:

```
awk -F";"  'NR==FNR{a[$4,$2];next} ($0) in a' file1 file2
```

The expected result can be just entire line from file1:

```
"202005";"RS";"4301602";"CITY";"12651500714";"***.368.660-**";"TESTE TESTE";"-2";""
```

Comment: Could you please add expected output in your post for better understanding of your question please.

Comment: The `join` command can do this for you. Search here for `[linux] join` or `[bash] join` . Good luck.``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this code:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"} FNR == NR {seen[$2]; next} $5 in seen' f2 f1
```

```
"202005";"RS";"4301602";"CITY";"12651500714";"***.368.660-**";"TESTE TESTE";"-2";""
```

This command will only print lines from file2 where 5th column from file1 is same as 2nd column from file2.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution is to use the *nix utility `join`.

```
 join -t\; -1 5 -2 2 -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9 f1.txt f2.txt
```

produces the output

```
"202005";"RS";"4301602";"CITY";"12651500714";"***.368.660-**";"TESTE TESTE";"-2";""
```

Note that both files need to be sorted by their key field. If your data needs sorting, this can be accomplished in-line using process substitution :

```
join -1 5 -2 2 -t\; <(sort -t\; -k5 f1.txt)  <(sort -t\; -l2 f2.txt)
```

Note also the flexibility of `join` in that you specify the key field number after the file number, ie, `-1 5` in this case.

Finally, note that if you wanted the "joined" output of both files the command would be simpler, i.e.

```
join -t\; -1 5 -2 2 f1.txt f2.txt
```

producing the output of the first file and the second file on one line. Note that the key field is not including in the file 2 output.

```
"12651500714";"202005";"RS";"4301602";"CITY";"***.368.660-**";"TESTE TESTE";"-2";"";"93330090006";"TESTE XX";
```

For beginners, the `man join` is rather a terse description of the features. Look for online tutorials that match your learning style, or search here, as there are many Q/As on the subject (often as an answer to a similar Q).

IHTH